# C# HttpListener Prefixes not accepting `ws` preventing JS WebSocket to connect

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

## Scenario

- C# Based Server
- JavaScript Based Client

## Situation

I created this fairly simple "server" which only job is to help me understanding how to actually use those websockets in a C# environment.

```
using (var server = new HttpListener())
{
    server.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
    server.Start();
    while(true)
    {
        var context = server.GetContext();
        if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            var cntxt = context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null).ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var buff = new byte[2048];
            while(cntxt.WebSocket.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Open || cntxt.WebSocket.State == System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketState.Connecting)
            {
                cntxt.WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buff), CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
            {
                writer.Write("<html><body>WEBSOCKET ONLY!</body></html>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is: when i try to add the websocket prefix via `server.Prefixes.Add("ws://localhost:8080")`, i get some `System.ArgumentException` thrown which tells my i can only add `http` and `https` as accepted protocol.

Thing is: doing it and using `ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');` (JavaScript) to connect to a websocket, yields for obvious reasons nothing.
Changing the prefix to HTTP in the JS websocket, will provide me with yet another sort-off argument exception.

## Actual Question

how to actually get the HttpListener to acceppt web socket requests?

## Further Info

Used `.net` framework is 4.6.1
Browser to test this was Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for why the above was not working ... is due to the JS websocket requiring a path.

Changing the above `HttpListener` prefix to eg. `"http://localhost:8080/asdasd/"` will allow the socket to connect propertly.

Comment: So how does it work on the javascript side, do you connect using "ws://localhost:8080/asdasd" or something else?

Comment: This answer is correct.  With localhost, the URL can be set to http:// - while on the client js side, it points to ws:// and the application appears to do the translation.